# How to use Keycloak IAM for react native app created using Expo?

Tags: react-native, redirect, expo, keycloak

I have used `npm package "react-native-login-keycloak": "^1.0.2"`
getting error while trying to define redirect URL.
following are the parameters used for config `keycloak`.

```
`const config = {
  url: 'https://<KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth',
  realm: '<REALM NAME>',
  clientId: '<CLIENT ID>',
  redirectUri: 'https://<REDIRECT HOST>/success.html',
  appsiteUri: 'https://<APPSITE HOST>/app.html',
  kcIdpHint: 'facebook', // *optional*
};`
```

Not able to get correct `redirectUri` for expo react-native app